# Programmatically Getting Name of Front-most (currently running) application in Unity

Tags: unity, scripts

I am trying to write a script that executes differently depending on the currently active program, and I am wondering if there is any way to find this programatically.

For example, I come from the Mac world, and in Apple's Applescript you can do the following:

```
set appPath to the path to the frontmost application
set appName to the name of file appPath
```

and that will give you the name of the currently running application.

Is there anything similar that I can do in ubuntu-land?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xprop` can tell you the ID of the window that is active

```
xprop -root|grep '^_NET_ACTI'
```

And you can use the output of `wmctrl` to find out the name of all windows, matched up to their IDs

```
wmctrl -l
```

`wmctrl` isn't in the default install, so you'll need to `sudo apt-get install wmctrl` of course.

Note that there's no left-padding in the output of `xprop`, so we need to pad it before grepping for it within the output of `wmctrl`. All together, something like this should do it:

```
$ WINID=$(xprop -root|grep '^_NET_ACTI' |sed -e 's/.*# //' -e 's/0x/0x0/')
$ wmctrl -l |grep $WINID
0x07c00006  0 my-hostname The Title of The Window
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!
(Haha, that's just about as readable as the applescript, I think.) :p